# Inverse coupon collector problem

Tags: probability, expected-value, coupon-collector

So in coupon collector, we calculated the purchases needed to get all coupons.

I wonder how to calculate the expected number of coupons seen given we made $k$ purchases.

Formally, we have points {1,2,3, $\cdots$, n}. Each point has probability $1/n$ to be drawn. If we make $m$ draws, and put each draw into a set $K$. What is the expected size of the set $K$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @saulspatz I am currently thinking on an inductive exploration. For the first draw, we always get 1 new coupon. However, for the $m$-th draw, we need to condition on the previous size. I am not sure how to write that out explicitly.

Comment: Linearity of expectation is the way to go.  See Henry's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- What is the probability that item $1$ is drawn in one attempt?
- What is the probability that item $1$ is not drawn in one attempt?
- What is the probability that item $1$ is not drawn in $m$ attempts?
- What is the probability that item $1$ is drawn at least once in $m$ attempts?
- What is the expected number of distinct items drawn at least once in $m$ attempts?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I do not see how to proceed from 4 to 5. For 4, it is just $1 - (1-1/n)^m$. Going to 5, I am confused. Is independence an issue here?

Comment: If we had independence, we could first find the expected number of un-drawn items. Hence expected number of drawn items is simply $n$ that minus that.

Comment: Oh I get it now. We do not need independence among anything but just the linearity of expectation allows us to sum things up! Your hints have been helpful. Thank you and also @saulspatz.

Comment: Yes - so the answer is $n\left(1 -  (1-1/n)^m\right)$.  As a check, when $m=1$ this gives the obvious answer of $1$